# Radial layout of Seekbars (Views) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

hi does anyone know how to layout multiple seekbars around a single point - like a radial pattern? also how to make them have varying lengths? (please see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG16W.jpg)). if it is easier please assume an even angle between seekbars.

iv messed around with android studio loads but cant get anything close. eventually i want to do this with java so i can add new bars on the fly but for now i will settle for just an xml solution.

thanks so much.

[sketch showing array of seekbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG16W.jpg)

Comment: You need radial menu or seekbar like radial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you judiciously arrange all you `seekbar's` at some position in `RelativeLayout`(i prefer relative layout, you can use other as well). Then set rotation property of `seekbar's` with angle values that satisfies your scenario.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:rotation="60"
/>
```